# Mocked interface is null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, unboxing, jmockit

I am trying to mock a DAO with JMockit:

```
public interface MyDao {
    Details getDetailsById(int id);
}
```

With this test class:

```
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void testStuff(final MyDao dao) throws Exception
    {
        new Expectations()
        {
            {
                // when we try to get the message details, return our sample
                // details
                dao.getDetailsById((Integer) any);  ***THROWS AN NPE
                result = sampleDetails;
            }
        };

        ClassUsingDao daoUser = new ClassUsingDao(dao);
        // calls dao.getDetailsById()
        daoUser.doStuff();
}
```

When the dao object is used in the Expectations block, an NPE is thrown. I've tried moving the declaration of dao to a member variable annotated with @Mocked, but the same thing happens. I've also tried using a concrete implementation of MyDao, and the same thing happens.

Comment: No, Spring isn't currently used in this class, but probably will be used to inject dao into ClassUsingDao in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `dao` that's null, but `any`. The unboxing from Integer (after your cast) to int involves a dereference, which throws a NullPointerException. Try using `anyInt` instead.

I don't think the jMockit documentation talks about what the actual value of [Expectations.any](http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/javadoc/mockit/Expectations.html#any) is, but note that it can be successfully cast to any other type (you can say `(String)any` and `(Integer)any`). The only value in Java for which all casts will always succeed is `null`. So, Expectations.any must be null. Bit of a surprise, but inevitable really.

Comment: Sure enough, that was it. Thanks for the help - I've spent hours moving that around and it was right in front of me. Thanks!